# Como utilizar a função ROUND no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query, laravel-eloquent

`insira o código aqui`Tenho a seguinte consulta no PHP:

```
$transferencia = $conecta->rawSelect(
    'SELECT * FROM register WHERE ROUND(valor,2)="' . $json->VALORLIQUIDO . '"  '
);
```

Como realizo essa mesma consulta utilizando o Eloquent Laravel?

Esse campo valor é um valor `float`.

tentei assim

```
$transferencia = Register::where('valor',$json->VALORLIQUIDO)->get()
```

Ele não encontra nenhum resultado, mesmo sendo certo que tem esse registro no banco, como a coluna tem um valor float a consulta não localiza o resultado.
Então preciso entender como realizar uma consulta no laravel utilizando o eloquent para buscando registros em colunas que tenha valores float.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Presumindo que vc tem o model de register criado corretamente.

```
$transferencia = Register::where('ROUND(valor,2)',$json->VALORLIQUIDO)->get();
$transferencia = Register::whereRaw('ROUND(valor,2)',$json->VALORLIQUIDO)->get();

DB::table('register')->whereRaw('ROUND(valor,2)', $json->VALORLIQUIDO)->get();
DB::table('register')->whereRaw('ROUND(valor,2)="' . $json->VALORLIQUIDO . '"')->get();
```

De uma testada nesses e dai um feedback

Comment: Mateus, no  caso dessa consulta acima eu não preciso indicar qual o coluna ?

Comment: Foi mal escrevi rapidão e esqueci

Comment: Mateus
Tentei assim
$valor = 1.11;

$register = Register::where('valor', $valor)->where(round($valor, 2),  $valor)->get();


message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1.11' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `register` where `valor` = 1.11 and `1`.`11` = 1.11)"

Comment: Agora que li com calma ali, tinha visto errado, ai nesse caso vc vai ter que usar DB::raw

Comment: Só ter um tempo já monto ali

Comment: Funcionou 100% Mateus! 
excelente solução.

Comment: @Murilo qual deles vc usou?